# What's the difference between using sinh/cosh and e^x/e^-x in solving boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that sometimes if we use e^x the boundary conditions gives only trivial solutions. But why is this the case? Isn't these two functions span the same set of functions?

Example $x''-x=0,
x(0)=0,x(1)=1$

Also is the solution actually unique?

Comment: I believe the choice boils down to which expression makes algebra simpler.

Comment: But why in solving PDE when finding eigen function we always use sinh and cosh?

Comment: Because such a choice of functions makes it easier to handle (homogeneous) boundary conditions since $\sinh(0) = 0$.